# Content aware resizing image at runtime

Tags: javascript, css

I find that the image on top of the site http://www.polygon.com/ seems to be resized "content aware". It looks really nice, how do they do this ?

The only thing I can imagine is they can draw an image on canvas, but i'm not sure. It would be nice that someone know this !

Comment: You really don't have to "imagine" anything.  You can always view all the source documents of any given page to see how they are accomplishing things.

Answer (score 1):

They use `background-size: cover; background-position: center;` to archive the result.

Answer (score 1):

… you gave the answer yourself, but just for reference, as the other answers were somehow correct as well:

- some years ago you usually used some sort of scripted scaling/cropping like [Backstretch](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch).
- nowadays, you rely on **background-size: cover** and use a [polyfill for IE](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill).

There are usecases where you still need scripted scaling: E.g. if you want to print the scaled image or handle other media like video iframes.

Comment: you can answer your own question since you figure things out on stackoverflow :P 
Your answer is very informative to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is called responsive design. You can read more about it here:

http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/

Looks like they are using CSS `overflow`,`left`,`top` control on top of responsive design (media queries)

Comment: I do know about responsive design, but the fact is you cannot scale an image like that. You have to somehow change another image that fit, but in this case, if you look closely, it does add more content not change the image.

Comment: I have done that with media queries. I would actually have two `<div>` tags with the content. I would switch from showing one or the other depending on screen size. As far as images being cropped - they seems to not be cropped but rather it **hides** more of the image on smaller screens using `overflow: hidden`

Comment: thanks for your answer. it still works, but I don't like the fact of creating multiple thumb. So I'm discovering another method that only need a big image :D